Unable to log into virtual console on Manjaro: "unix_chkpwd[129255]: password check failed for user"
Since I switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro several months ago, I've had a weird problem: I haven't been able to log into the virtual console, always getting a "Login incorrect" message, although all the other authentication has worked perfectly. Today, I finally decided to solve that, but did not succeed.
getty seems to run normally and invoke login as expected.
$ ps auxww |grep getty
root      129384  0.0  0.0   7176  3880 tty3     Ss+  22:47   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear - linux

I checked there's no leftover /etc/nologin or /var/run/nologin, and the related configs (/etc/login.defs, /etc/security/*) are totally untouched and quite permissive distro defaults.
Nevertheless, when trying to log into the VC, I'm getting (after enabling the debug option for some PAM modules):
dic 06 22:46:53 s0me0ne login[128494]: pam_systemd_home(login:auth): pam-systemd-homed authenticating
dic 06 22:46:53 s0me0ne login[128494]: pam_systemd_home(login:auth): New sd-bus connection (system-bus-pam-systemd-home-128494) opened.
dic 06 22:46:53 s0me0ne login[128494]: pam_systemd_home(login:auth): systemd-homed is not available: Could not activate remote peer 'org.freedesktop.home1': activation request failed: unknown unit
dic 06 22:46:53 s0me0ne login[128494]: pam_unix(login:auth): username [s0me0ne] obtained
dic 06 22:46:55 s0me0ne unix_chkpwd[129255]: password check failed for user (s0me0ne)
dic 06 22:46:55 s0me0ne login[128494]: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty3 ruser= rhost=  user=s0me0ne
dic 06 22:46:56 s0me0ne login[128494]: FAILED LOGIN 1 FROM tty3 FOR s0me0ne, Authentication failure

I double-checked that all the unix_chkpwd instances present in the system are SUID root and are hardlinks to the same binary:
$ ls -li /usr/bin/unix_chkpwd /sbin/unix_chkpwd                                                                                                                                               
220202420 -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 26672 18 nov 12.58 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
220202420 -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 26672 18 nov 12.58 /usr/bin/unix_chkpwd


Then I recalled the old good pamtester and gave it a try:
$ pamtester -v login s0me0ne authenticate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 pamtester: invoking pam_start(login, s0me0ne, ...)
pamtester: performing operation - authenticate
Password: 
pamtester: successfully authenticated

Worked like a charm, and PAM is happy, no errors in logs.
The last thing I tried is manually testing the unix_chkpwd functionality itself:
$ mkfifo /tmp/pw
$ echo -ne 'mypassword\0' >/tmp/pw &
[1] 137112
$ /sbin/unix_chkpwd s0me0ne nullok </tmp/pw
[1]  + done       echo -ne 'mypassword\0' > /tmp/pw
$ echo $?
0

At this point, I'm completely stuck and scratching my head. Any thoughts are appreciated.

It turned out to be a ridiculously silly configuration bug.
The console keymap in /etc/vconsole.conf was set to Croatian, which is QWERTZ, and my keyboard is QWERTY. So when I was entering my username, which doesn't contain any ys and zs, it looked like the keymap was totally okay. But the y in my password was replaced with z.
All the other tests were done under X11, and my xkb keymaps were QWERTY and worked fine.
